# Parameters/arguments in dos

Tags: batch-file

I googled and i couldn't find any helpful and clear information on parameters in dos (those commands with "%"). Can someone explain a little what parameters and arguments in dos are, and how to use commands like %~f1  , %~d1  , %~f1.

Here is some example of code i have trouble understanding.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO full path %~f1
ECHO disc %~d1
ECHO extension %~x1
ECHO disc and directory %~dp1
ECHO file name and extension %~nx1
pause
```

And when i open this .bat file, nothing appears in place of %~f1 and all other "%", just echoed text.

Comment: `batchname.bat "c:\windows\notepad.exe"` <--- launch your batch file like this and you will see the output that you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `1` in `%~f1`, is the 1st argument supplied to the program at the command line. So if you are running your batch file `myBatch`, and passing it a first argument of `C:\Users\bliny\Desktop\textFile.txt`, the output would look like this:

```
myBatch C:\Users\bliny\Desktop\textFile.txt
full path C:\Users\bliny\Desktop\textFile.txt
disc C:
extension .txt
disc and directory C:\Users\bliny\Desktop
file name and extension textFile.txt
```

Running `myBatch` alone will produce no output because no arguments are supplied.

From [Microsoft's documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true):

On batch parameters:

> You can use batch parameters anywhere within a batch file to extract
>   information about your environment settings. Cmd.exe provides the
>   batch parameter expansion variables %0 through %9. When you use batch
>   parameters in a batch file, %0 is replaced by the batch file name, and
>   %1 through %9 are replaced by the corresponding arguments that you
>   type at the command line.

On modifiers:

> You can also use modifiers with batch parameters. Modifiers use
>   current drive and directory information to expand the batch parameter
>   as a partial or complete file or directory name. To use a modifier,
>   type the percent (%) character followed by a tilde (~) character, and
>   then type the appropriate modifier (that is, %~modifier).